# How to pass parameter from constructor parameter to viewmodel constructor in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

```
public partial class DenomDetailPage : Page
    {
        public DenomDetailPage(IEnumerable<TbTrans002> t)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new DenomDetailViewModel(t);
        }
    }
```

My simple test code is on top.
But, I want to set the datacontext in xaml file.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:DenomDetailViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

on above code is error occured. How to fix my code.

Comment: Why do you want to set the DataContext in XAML? This should be avoided in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in XAML2009 via `x:Arguments` but BAML doesn't support XAML2009 features, so in WPF you have to use an ObjectDataProvider instead:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type viewmodel:YourClass}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <sys:String>Constructor parameter 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Constructor parameter 2</sys:String>
            <sys:Double>3</sys:Double>
            <sys:String>etc</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Page.DataContext>
```